# Storing a character string in a variable

Tags: c

Would someone explain how it is possible to store a string (or character array) in a char array of lesser length? For example, take the below example.

```
int main()
{
   char ls_thread[10];
   sprintf(ls_thread,"Learning C is %s\n","fun");
   printf("%s",ls_thread);
   printf("Length of the string is %d",strlen(ls_thread));
   return 0; 
}
```

Also what are potential problems that may arise?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behaviour. You have a buffer ovewrflow here, and as soon as that happens you're in the domain of undefined behaviour (which includes "apparently working fine"). There are no potential problems with your code, there is an _actual_ problem with your code.

Comment: ls_thread has buffer oberflow, You overwrite "something", in C say Undefined Behaviour

Comment: It sounds as if you try to fill a bathtub full of water into a bucket. It's not clear what you try to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing in your code is *invalid write*.

Consider the memory

```
[-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-] ...
|       reserved memory       |      non reserved memory     ...
```

---

What you are doing is writing on the memory you asked for, but also in the memory you didn't :

```
[L][e][a][r][n][i][n][g][ ][C][ ][i][s][ ][f][u][n][\n][\0][-] ...
|       reserved memory       |      non reserved memory     ...
```

---

Writing in a memory that isn't yours will result to *undefined behavior*, because it can act on some other program memory or even yours.

---

You have to be rigorous using C language, only use what you have asked for.

When you use `malloc`, use `free`; then everything will be ok.

Comment: I will point out that due to [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) it is _extremely unlikely_ that you would overwrite another process' memory on a modern operating system; the main risk is writing other memory belonging to your own process

Comment: @GovindParmar With billions of embedded processor each year, I would how (un)likely the virtual machine/multi-processor issue is there.

Answer (score 2):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Just because your compiler produced a binary out of the source code - does not mean the code is *legit*. Accessing beyond allocated memory is undefined behavior.

In your code, `ls_thread` has 10 members, that indicates it is only good to hold a 9-`char` *string*, plus one null-terminator. Attempt to access past the 10th element is a venture into *invalid* memory, which causes the UB.